# How to make SVG not stretch?

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have an SVG background and I have a fixed white box on top of the SVG background. When I make the browser size height bigger, the SVG expands as well, causing a huge space between the white box and the svg. How can I stop the svg from expanding from browser size?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1441 668" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 60.1 (101010) - https://sketch.com -->
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Asset-Artboard-Page" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="bg-bg-new" transform="translate(0.975610, 0.000000)">
            <g id="bg-geo" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.000000)">
                <rect id="bg" fill="#279BE8" x="0" y="0" width="1440" height="668"></rect>
                <polygon id="green" fill="#44CF50" points="680 668 -7.54951657e-14 320 0 668"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-light" fill="#FFFFFF" points="364 0 0 264 0 0"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-dark" fill="#103C63" points="136 668 798 188 1440 518 1440 668"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-light" fill="#E6F9FC" points="987 668 1440 340 1440 668"></polygon>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Try setting fixed width and height to your svg element

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed width and height on the `svg` container. The `svg` takes the parent's dimension if the width and height are not set.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1441 668" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300">
    <!-- Generator: sketchtool 60.1 (101010) - https://sketch.com -->
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Asset-Artboard-Page" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="bg-bg-new" transform="translate(0.975610, 0.000000)">
            <g id="bg-geo" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.000000)">
                <rect id="bg" fill="#279BE8" x="0" y="0" width="1440" height="668"></rect>
                <polygon id="green" fill="#44CF50" points="680 668 -7.54951657e-14 320 0 668"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-light" fill="#FFFFFF" points="364 0 0 264 0 0"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-dark" fill="#103C63" points="136 668 798 188 1440 518 1440 668"></polygon>
                <polygon id="blue-light" fill="#E6F9FC" points="987 668 1440 340 1440 668"></polygon>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```